# Only first line of sql command is getting executed in sqldeveloper

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

I am creating few tables using oracle database and sqldeveloper.

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER
( CUSTOMER_ID NUMBER,
FIRST_NAME VARCHAR2(50),
LAST_NAME VARCHAR2(50),
MIDDLE_NAME VARCHAR2(50),
ADDRESS_LINE1 VARCHAR2(80),
ADDRESS_LINE2 VARCHAR2(80),
CITY VARCHAR2(40),
COUNTRY VARCHAR2(50),
DATE_ADDED DATE,
REGION VARCHAR2(10)
);
CREATE TABLE PRODUCT
( PRODUCT_ID NUMBER,
PRODUCT_NAME VARCHAR2(100),
STANDARD_COST NUMBER(10,2),
COLOR VARCHAR2(20),
LIST_PRICE NUMBER(10,2),
PRODUCT_SIZE NUMBER(8,2),
WEIGHT NUMBER(10,2),
PRODUCT_CATEGORY VARCHAR2(20)
);
CREATE TABLE SALES
( SALES_DATE DATE,
ORDER_ID NUMBER,
PRODUCT_ID NUMBER,
CUSTOMER_ID NUMBER(5,0),
SALESPERSON_ID NUMBER(5,0),
QUANTITY NUMBER(4,0),
UNIT_PRICE NUMBER(10,2),
SALES_AMOUNT NUMBER(10,2),
TAX_AMOUNT NUMBER(10,2),
TOTAL_AMOUNT NUMBER(10,2)
);
CREATE TABLE SALES_HISTORY
( SALES_DATE DATE,
ORDER_ID NUMBER,
PRODUCT_ID NUMBER,
CUSTOMER_ID NUMBER(5,0),
SALESPERSON_ID NUMBER(5,0),
QUANTITY NUMBER(4,0),
UNIT_PRICE NUMBER(10,2),
SALES_AMOUNT NUMBER(10,2),
TAX_AMOUNT NUMBER(10,2),
TOTAL_AMOUNT NUMBER(10,2)
);
CREATE TABLE SALESPERSON
( SALESPERSON_ID NUMBER,
JOB_TITLE VARCHAR2(80),FIRST_NAME VARCHAR2(50),
LAST_NAME VARCHAR2(50),
MIDDLE_NAME VARCHAR2(50),
ADDRESS_LINE1 VARCHAR2(80),
ADDRESS_LINE2 VARCHAR2(80),
CITY VARCHAR2(40),
COUNTRY VARCHAR2(50),
DATE_ADDED DATE
);
```

but only **Customer** table is created and not other table like **Product**,**Sales**....etc.
[image]

It would be really helpful if any one answer why this is happening.
I am new to sql so any help would be helpful

Comment: Did you use "Run Statement" or "Run Script"?